# Comparing means of 2 time series

Tags: time-series, mean

My question is about comparing means of 2 different populations. 
Characteristics: the data points are not independent of each other [within each process]; the data points do not form a uniform distribution.
I have 2 data sets (one for each process: Real data / Model data); each point represents number of patients in a clinic by minute of the days: TIME (R, M). An example of non-independence: 10.00 (9, 13); 10.01 (10, 12); 10.02 (12, 10). Thus, for the Real data, in 10.01, 10 patients is dependent on 10.00 (one patient more from 10.00), and 10.02 is dependent on 10.01 (+2 from 10.01). The same goes for the Model data.
From my understanding, I cannot use z or t tests because it is not a normal distribution; furthermore, the data points are not independent.
What statistical tools are there that I can use in order to compare the 2 means? How do I make sure, statistically, that the 2 (Real vs. Model are similar? [visually, they are and they follow the same fluctuations]

Comment: Although independence has a clear definition, lack of independence covers a lot of different behaviors and needs to be described.  What is the reason for the lack of independence and what quantitative assumptions can you make about the dependencies among the data?

Comment: I have 2 data sets (one for each process: Real data / Model data); each point represents number of patients in a clinic by minute of the days: TIME (R, M). An example of non-independence: 10.00 (9, 13); 10.01 (10, 12); 10.02 (12, 10). Thus, for the Real data, in 10.01, 10 patients is dependent on 10.00 (one patient more from 10.00), and 10.02 is dependent on 10.01 (+2 from 10.01). The same goes for the Model data.

Comment: That is a crucial piece of your problem, Alex, and needs to be clearly described in your post itself.

Comment: Thank you for your input Whuber. I re-edited the main post.